# Vim - Session management issues

Tags: vim, gvim, session, session-manager

When I save and load a session (with split, vsplit and a different file) in Vim (or Gvim) with `:mks` and `:source`, or with a session manager plugin I can't load what I saved.

For example :

======= What I save ======

```
:mks ~/.vim/sessions/Session.vim

 —————————————————————————
|  1   |       2          |
|      |——————————————————|
|——————|                  |
|  3   |          4       |
|______|__________________|
```

4 differents file, 1 vsplit and 2 split ( different height ).

======= What I get ======

```
:source ~/.vim/sessions/Session.vim

 —————————————————————————
|  1 |       4     |  1   |
|————|             |      |
|    |_____________|______|
|  2 |       3     |  3   |
|____|_____________|______|
```

Two files ( 1 and 3 ) opened twice.
Order change.
Split and vsplit size and position are not the same.

Does anyone know why this happens?
It's very painfull to manage sessions with things like that.

```
-> vim --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.3 (2010 Aug 15, compiled Jul 28 2011 16:03:36)
```

( Full 'vim --version' : http://pastebin.com/cCs19jwP)

Comment: Does it still happen when you do "vim -N -u NONE" and save/restore a session?

Comment: Seems to work …

Comment: I will have to find which plugin dont work well …
Painful work :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found the evil plugin. It's [MiniBufferExplorer](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=159).

I tested without all plugins except for MiniBufferExplorer and I get the issue. I'm still not sure why though.